# Gas fireplace, “log” placement, and flame flare up

Tags: fireplace

I recently bought a house that has a gas fireplace. It seems to work well (although the fan is too loud to actually use—perhaps a future DIY question!), but to the right there’s a large flame that isn’t really “hitting” the logs. It seems to me that the fire warming the ceramic logs is really what radiates the heat. The flame to the right is just shooting it’s heat right out the exhaust.

Should I open the fireplace and look at how I might adjust the placement of the logs to ensure they are over the flame? Or, is this working as intended?

[image: See large flame to right]

Comment: ive seen something like that happen when the sand/gravel gets displaced and too shallow in a spot. maybe redistribute. if not, then its a pipe leaking, and you need a plumber or fireplace guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would stop using the fireplace until a detailed inspection has been done of the gas piping and gas jet manifold. It would appear that there is a gas leak coming from part of the piping assembly. This could be from a loose or dried out pipe joint or some malfunction part of the gas jet system.

From the appearance of the picture I would venture to guess that this could be a pretty dangerous situation until it is fixed.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion. What kind of professional am I looking for?